# How I can find all the items matching between two arrays if the array is too big (more than 700k entries) and not freeze the browser

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two lists one with 1k objects, and another one with more than 700k objects. I need to create a new list that contains the items with the same latitude and longitude. Both lists have id,address,latitude and longitude, but the only possible matches are lat and long.
Also just iterating over the large array freezes the browser and the pc.
For small lists this works fine but with bigger lists it starts to freeze.

```
 bigList.forEach((item) => {
  smallList.forEach((compare) => {
    if (compare.latitude == item.latitude && compare.longitude == item.longitude) {
      if (matchingList.length > 0) {
        let exists = false;
        matchingList.forEach((stored) => {
          if (stored.address != compare.address) {
            console.log(stored.address);
            console.log(compare.address);
            console.log('--------');
          }
        });
        if (!exists) matchingList.push(compare);
      } else {
        matchingList.push(compare);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Going 1000 times through a list of 700000 objects should take a bit, that's not very unusual. Please share code so we can help optimize. I would go as far as to say don't do this in the browser if you can avoid it.

Comment: If it is not unusual, then how is the propper way to find something in two lists and one list could have repeated values that also have to be stored in the result list

Comment: I'm saying it is not unusual that it takes a long time, since that is 700,000,000 loops. Having a backend with a database and quering the matching records would be a better way. With proper indexing that may only take seconds even with shared hosting.

Comment: I mean, how can loop and fin in a more efficien way? Even if it is small lists I dont think the correct way is to loop inside loop inside an if etc. Thanks

Comment: Oh I see now. The loop seems pretty much the minimum. The main problem is the large amount of objects to traverse. You would remove the console.log calls in the end but that would also just affect matched elements. You should at least move this to an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your algorithm when pasted into a standalone TypeScript IDE?  Right now `bigList`, `smallList`, and `matchingList` are not defined, and you don't seem to be doing *anything* with `exists`.  If you can give values of these (not the full 1k/700k but a more manageable example), then someone could possibly refactor the algorithm to be more performant.  But right now it's hard to tell.  The goal of a [mre] is to help others immediately get to work on your problem instead of first neeting to re-create it.

Comment: If you do [edit] the question to include a plaintext [mre] and you want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz so I'm notified.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a CPU limited problem. The first thing to realize is that the time complexity of finding the union of these two arrays is going to be O(n^2) if you just search through them all manually.

I would suggest making a map/object for `smallList` where the keys are the latitude/longitude. Then, your code can be reduced to this:

```
bigList.forEach((item) => {
    const latlong: string = item.latitude + item.longitude
    // look up the latlong in smallListIndexed in O(1), 
    // which is surely faster than iterating 1000 entries.
    const compare = smallListIndexed[latlong]
    if (compare) { // do whatever
        if (matchingList.length > 0) {
            let exists = false;
            matchingList.forEach((stored) => {
                if (stored.address != compare.address) {
                    console.log(stored.address);
                    console.log(compare.address);
                    console.log('--------');
                }
            });
            if (!exists) matchingList.push(compare);
        } else {
            matchingList.push(compare);
        }
    }
});
```

I disagree with the suggestion to move this to an `async` function. This is obviously a CPU-limited task, and simply adding `async` to a function makes no difference (with anything, really, `async` does nothing unless you have an `await` inside your function...)

What you can do, to prevent the browser from freezing (but not to speed up the process), is to do this filtering inside of a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), which will run in a separate thread than the browser UI and won't freeze it.